# Jenkins MSBuild returns msb1009 "Project file does not exist"

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am trying to perform a .NET build with MSBuild in Jenkins on a Windows server, and no matter what I do, I get an error `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.`

The command being run correctly defines the name of the sln file, and I have even tried to define the full path to the file with `%WORKSPACE%\project.sln`, but neither fix the issue.

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the default workspace path defined by Jenkins on a Windows OS. It was placing the project files in a path like `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\RandomQuotes`.

If I ran the MSBuild command from a command prompt specifying the sln file (either with a full or relative path, I got the same `MSB1009` error.

If I ran the command without the sln file, I got the error `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\RandomQuotes'`.

I suspect the issue here is the path is too long. The solution was to edit the jenkins.xml file used to launch the Jenkins service and change the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable to something like `C:\JenkinsHome`.

Comment: `systemprofile` might not have the needed permission to ba able to access it by normaluser profiles